# Best practice for WCF Duplex client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, architecture, duplex

I can't deny the performance benefit of a duplex async call, but some things about makes me feel wary.

My concern is that given a client object instantiated, will WCF be able to tell which particular client service instance will receive the callback argument?

Can anyone tell me if this is a good idea? If not why not?

```
new DuplexChannelFactory<IServerWithCallback>(
   new ClientService(), 
   new NetTcpBinding(), 
   new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:1234/"+Guid.NewGuid()))
```

1. If the virtual path above is reserved how can it be discarded. I want the client service lifetime to be fairly short. IE make a request and receive a response and when done receiving, kill it. How bad is the performance penalty in making the client service lifetime short as opposed to pooling it and keeping it alive longer.

   The idea is to avoid timeout issue. When done receiving, sending, dispose ASAP. By convention - can't pass the client services around. If you need info, create a new one, simple - just like EF/L2S etc.
2. From inside the WCF service itself, how do I kill the session with the client. ie. I don't want the client ending the session - I know I can decorate my operation accordingly, but I want the service to terminate itself programmatically when certain conditions are met.
3. I can affix the port and forward accordingly to resolve any firewall issue, but what I'm worried about is if the client were to sit behind a load-balancer. How would the service know which particular server to call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think in the end Duplex services is simply another failed architecture from Microsoft. This is one of those things that looked really good on paper but just falls apart upon closer examination.

There are too many weaknesses:

1) Reliance on session to establish client listener by the server. This is session information is stored in memory. Hence the server itself cannot be load balanced. Or if it were load balanced you need to turn ip affinity on, but now if one of the servers is bombarded you can't simply add another one and expect all these sessions to automagically migrate over to the new server.

2) For each client sitting behind a router/firewall/loadbalancer, a new end point with specific port needs to be created. Otherwise the router will not be able to properly route the callback messages to the appropriate client. An alternative is to have a router that allows custom programming to redirect specific path to a particular server. Again a tall order. Or another way is for the client with the callback to host its own database and share data via a database <-- Might work in some situation where licensing fees is not an issue... but it introduces a lot of complexity and so onerous on the client plus it mixes the application and services layer together (which might be acceptable in some exceptional situation, but not on top of the huge setup cost)

3) All this basically says that duplex is practically useless. If you need call back then you will do well to setup a wcf host on the client end. It will be simpler and much more scalable. Plus there is less coupling between client and server.

The best duplex solution for scalable architecture is in the end not using one.

Comment: Is this answer true for NetTcpBinding or just to Dual Http binding?

Answer (score 3):

1. It will depend on how short you need the clients new'd up and how long they will last.  Pooling would not be an option if you specifically need a new client each time, but if the clients keep doing the same thing why not have a pool of them waiting to be used, if they fault out recreate that same client again.
2. In reality in a callback scenario if the service is calling back to the client (really calling a function on the client) to pass information the service is now the client and vice versa.  You can have the service that's making the callback .Close() the connection but it will be open until the GC can dispose of it, from my experience that can take longer than expected.  So in short the client should be responsible (the client being the one making the call to something) for shutting itself down, or disconnecting, the service should only give back answers or take data from a client.
3. In duplex callbacks the service now calling back to the client will get the address of the client abstracted behind the duplexchannelfactory.  If the service can't call back to the client I don't think there's much that can be done, you'd have to ensure the port that your clients are calling to the service is open to receive callbacks I would guess.