# Using quartz.net, get callback for status from remote WCF service

Tags: wcf, quartz-scheduler, wcf-binding, quartz.net

Probably a common pattern, but I haven't been able to find any help.

I have an ASP.NET web application hosting Quartz, and I have job that fires on schedule. The job calls a remote WCF service:

```
public class SimpleJob : IJob {
    public SimpleJob() { 

    }
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) {
        // call some remote service at
        // http://someserver.com/someservice.svc/StartSomething
        // that could take hours to complete
    }
}
```

The StartSomething endpoint will run for a long time, so I cannot just wait for an http response 200. But, when it's done, **I want the remote process to tell Quartz that it's done**, thereby activating my IJobListener, and also do it's regular Quartz stuff. So, it's a fire-and-forget job, with a callback.

How can I accomplish this?

**Idea 1**

I could create an endpoint in my own application, like this:

```
http://myserver.com/Quartz/JobComplete?jobId=1234
```

The remote service would call this endpoint. But, what's the Quartz API to tell Quartz that a job has completed?

**Idea 2**

After posting this question, and reading some more, I found a different solution. It would work, but seems like it would really mess with Quartz's thread pool. Here's the link: http://www.interworks.com/blogs/banderton/2009/10/30/long-running-tasks-aspnet. In short, my IJob implementation would go into a loop, polling the remote service until it's done.

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) {
    var jobComplete = false;
    // call remote service
    while(jobComplete == false){
        var currentJobStatus = // ge tstatus from remote service
        if(status == complete) {
            jobComplete = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Idea 3**

Another route would be some kind of WCF Pub/Sub. Perhaps a WCF duplex callback. But, I read that it's flaky and I should avoid it: [Best practice for WCF Duplex client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125442/best-practice-for-wcf-duplex-client). But, if that's wrong, I'm willing to try it. I've also read that this pattern can be accomplished with MSMQ over WCF. But, it sounds like (without Azure Queue) that's a trail of tears.

Still, with any Pub/Sub I've got the issue of telling Quartz that the job has ended. How would I do that?

Comment: Doing it all with within `SimpleJob` may not be practical. It sounds like you need two jobs, one that triggers `StartSomething` and one that signals its completion. If this is ok I can write an answer showing different ways to do it.

Comment: Thank you, CircularReference. That is the same idea that @alioza proposed. It would work well, but I ended up removing the callback entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your question, I would suggest going with Idea 1 with some modifications.

You could define two jobs with the following flow (a sort of a two-step job):

1. The regular main job fires automatically on schedule.
2. It creates a second job with no trigger (new job id=XYZ). It makes the WCF call and then ends.
3. The remote service calls your endpoint when it has to, with the id of the new job (XYZ). You create a trigger for the new job to execute immediately.
4. The second-step job executes, you can clean up or whatever you need to do in it and it ends naturally.

I would recommend that in step 2 you create a job with a later trigger to act as a timeout in case the remote service never calls your endpoint back.

Comment: This definitely makes sense, and would fit the requirements. So, I went down this road. And, as I was implementing the second job, I had to ask myself "Why am I adding this job? Is it just to store the response in my own log repository?" Now, rather than a call-and-response for each individual job, I ended up eliminating the callback. The Quartz job just goes fire-and-forget. Then, the user has a different screen to get remote processes by status, or by ID. This also has the effect that the remote service can conform to a Workflow Service.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for my requirement? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74403074/asp-net-core-2-1-calling-rest-api-in-a-schedule)